# Future relative date format in git commit --date

Tags: git, date

While I was playing [githug](https://github.com/Gazler/githug) game task #20: commit_in_future. It requires the user to make a commit in the future.

I know that `--date` option from `git commit --date` supports relative date. But the following future relative date formats don't work for me.

```sh
❯ git commit --date="tomorrow"
fatal: invalid date format: tomorrow
```

And `git commit --date="1 day later"` is used as `--date="1 day ago"` from the log `git log --format=fuller`.

Obvious, I can pass a date with RFC2822 format or ISO8601 to `--date` to complete the task. But what did I do wrong with the relative date format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git's approxidate functionality doesn't deal with dates in the future.  In general, Git deals with the history of things, and the history of things is in the past (unless people have broken clocks).  Git does understand some basic words about time, such as “day” and “days”, but those always refer to times in the past (“7 days” is equivalent to “7 days ago”).  The exception is a handful of dates that refer to the present day (e.g., “noon” and “tea”).

If you want to falsify your commit dates into the future, you'll need to specify an actual timestamp.  Also, be sure not to sign your commits, since GnuPG embeds a timestamp in the signature.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although I haven't found any official statement yet, the lost of future relative support could be consolidated in the source code [date.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bc12974a897308fd3254cf0cc90319078fe45eea/date.c) and test case [t/t0006-date.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bc12974a897308fd3254cf0cc90319078fe45eea/t/t0006-date.sh). In date.c file, there's past keywords included, like "yesterday", "ago", "last", but not any future keywords.